# What is the MemberValue for a ComboBox which is bound to a List<string>?

Tags: c#, list, winforms, data-binding, combobox

What is the `ValueMamber` for a `ComboBox` which is bound to a `List<string>`?

I am using windows forms and .NET Framework 4.

```
  cmbForms.DataSource = Forms;
  cmbForms.ValueMember="System.String";
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PhotoDescription.Details.Form))
  {
      cmbForms.SelectedValue = PhotoDescription.Details.Form;
  }
```

Where `Forms` is:

```
 public List<string> Forms { get; set; }
```

Comment: I suppose it should be `System.String`. why not try yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)

> If a property is not specified in ValueMember, SelectedValue returns
>   the results of the ToString method of the object.

**Edit based on update**

You'll get an `ArgumentException` with your code because `System.String` is not a property that can be resolved (your `string` objects don't have a property called `System.String`). The default value, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx), will be an empty string `("")`.

In this case, you don't need to set the `ValueMember` property and so you can use `SelectedItem` instead.

```
cmbForms.DataSource = Forms;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PhotoDescription.Details.Form))
{
   cmbForms.SelectedItem = PhotoDescription.Details.Form;
}
```

Comment: "" gives me error Cannot set the SelectedValue in a ListControl with an empty ValueMember.

Comment: Yes, you haven't set a `ValueMember` so that's why you're getting the error. What are you trying to do, there's likely a different approach?

Comment: the whole code is in the question, just try to set the value of a combobox based on a simple if condition.

Comment: Then use `cmbForms.SelectedItem` instead of `cmbForms.SelectedValue` as you don't need to set the `ValueMember` property. (See updated answer)